# CSS Transition White Flash

Tags: html, css, flash, transition

All I am trying to accomplish is a transition to a brighter hue (using opacity) using CSS and I have already attempted the -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden trick and it didn't work. Flashes white over hover and it's driving me nuts!!

http://jsfiddle.net/eb3Lp0s0/

CSS

```
.button {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:25px;
    display:block;
   border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
   background: #0083d4;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0099ff), to(#0083d4));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0099ff, #0083d4);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0099ff, #0083d4);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0099ff, #0083d4);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0099ff, #0083d4);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color:#272727;
   font-size: 18px;
   font-family: 'Century Gothic', Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   text-transform:uppercase;
  opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
-o-backface-visibility: hidden;

  }
.button:hover {
   border-top-color: #28597a;
   background: #28597a;
   color: #ccc;
     opacity: 0.75;
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

   }
.button:active {
   border-top-color: #1b435e;
   background: #1b435e;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

HTML

```
<button type="button"  onclick="location.href='http://webwavebuilding.com/whatwedo.html'" class="button">Learn more</button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `background-color` on `:hover`, not just `background`:

```
.button:hover {
    border-top-color: #28597a;
    background-color: #28597a;  /* <<< Here */
    color: #ccc;
    opacity: 0.75;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eb3Lp0s0/1/

Usually, if you want to set only the *`background-color`* specifically, don't use the shorthand `background`, use the specific property.

Another way to fix it is to set the gradient to `background-color` in the `.button` class:

```
.button {
    background-color: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0099ff), to(#0083d4));
    background-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0099ff, #0083d4);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eb3Lp0s0/2/

Or add the color to the combined `background`:

```
background: #0083d4 -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0099ff), to(#0083d4));
background: #0083d4 -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0099ff, #0083d4);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eb3Lp0s0/3/

Which I think indicates what's going on here: Using `background:` for the gradient *resets* the entire `background-` set of values, including the implicit `background-color`. So even though you've set it right before you've called the `background: -webkit-gradient()` lines, those two lines are actually *removing* (by reset) the implicit `background-color`, which then becomes `background-color: transparent;`. Hence the flash.

Comment: That's truly weird! I wonder why that should make a difference, but it does.

Comment: I think it has to do with the transition, seeing as the previous state transitions from a more specific property and the flash is from those being transitioned before the color is set for the background. That's just a guess, though.

Comment: And if you remove the gradient, the flash goes away. So either it's a bug with gradients and hover transitions, or as I said above there's a brief moment where the transition works on the gradient and it's background is transparent (which could *be* the bug). The latter seems likely, if you set the background color on the body it's what shows through.

Comment: Hmmm... I wouldn't even have thought of that, kudos men! I gotta keep reading so I can know little intricacies like this.

Comment: This worked great for Chrome! I'm still getting the issue in IE though :/   but that is seriously amazingly helpful!

Comment: I'm guessing adding `background: #28597a -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0099ff, #0083d4);` should fix that.